# ASP.NET Web Api - Target URI and deployment

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api

So I'm brand new to developing an API, I have an existing MVC website which is published on Azure, and I would like to create my API using the ASP.NET Web Api template in a new project.

My question is in deployment. How can I deploy this API so that the target address is like:

> www.MyMVCWebsite.com/api/etc...

I don't want to modify my existing MVC site to contain the api as I've seen some posts mention that it is less secure, and all tutorials I've seen are for the web api template and I'm learning this from scratch.

Within the publish to azure settings in visual studio it gives the option to publish to an existing site...would this achieve what I want or is there more to it?

JK

Answer (score 1):

You just need to configure the `routes` to what you want it to be.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "API Default",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

See [Here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: Thanks, I do understand the routing settings, but if for instance I have Project A deployed to a certain URL....if I deploy a separate ASP.NET Web Api project to the same URL will this routing work automatically? Will my site be there as normal but the api project handle any API requests?

Comment: @JonnyKnottsvill To the same website under IIS or a different one?

Comment: The same website in Azure. There is a built in option to publish an ASP.NET project to an existing Azure location...I wondered if the ASP.NET web API would work in tandem with my MVC site at that location, or if I should attempt to build the web api into my MVC site

Comment: @JonnyKnottsvill I don't know the answer to this, but I suspect if you deployed it to an existing Azure website it would overwrite what is already there. You could easily Integrate your WebApi project and MVC project and it would work. You could always create a new Web Api project in Azure and just link up your domain?

Comment: I'm just not sure how I would link it up to the same domain. I will probably go down the route of creating the api within my MVC site.

Comment: @JonnyKnottsvill No problem, sorry i couldn't help as much as you wanted.

Comment: It's fine I think it's the question is a little confusing. Upvoted anwyay for routing help